# jqGrid prmNames sidx

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

How does jqGrid determine what to populate prmNamess' sidx with initially (when a grid is first loaded)?  My grid has 5 columns:

```
colNames: ['ID', 'Meta Name', 'Meta Value', 'Meta Owner ID', 'Comment']
```

The `Meta Owner` field is being sent in my POST variables...

- $_POST['sidx'] = 'metaownerid+asc,+'
- $_POST['sord'] = 'asc'

Additionally why is the order included in `sidx` when it is also automatically sent in `sord`?  It's not a big deal to receive the data in this way but might rather change what is sent how then to chop the string up in PHP.  I want `sidx` to contain the field only - no order.

Is there a logical reason it works out of the box the way it does that I am missing?

Thanks.

=== EDIT 1===
Some additional info...

```
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: 'data.php', 
    editurl: "data.php", 
    mtype: 'POST', 
    datatype: 'json', 

    colModel: 
    [
        {
            name: 'metaid', 
            index: 'metaid', 
            editable: true, 
            editoptions: 
            {
                disabled: true, 
                size: 27
            }, 
            hidden: false, 
            sorttype: 'int', 
            width: 50
        }, 

        {
            name: 'metaname', 
            index: 'metaname', 
            editable: true, 
            sorttype: 'text', 
            editoptions: { size: 27 }, 
        }, 

        {
            name: 'metavalue', 
            index: 'metavalue', 
            editable: true, 
            editoptions: { size: 27 }, 
            sorttype: 'text'
        }, 

        {
            name: 'metaownerid', 
            index: 'metaownerid', 
            editable: true, 
            edittype: 'select', 
            editoptions:
            {
                multiple: false, 
                value: '<?php echo $ownerSelectString; ?>'
            }
        }, 

        {
            name: 'comment', 
            index: 'comment', 
            editable: true, 
            editoptions: { size: 27 }, 
            sorttype: 'text'
        }
    ], 

    prmNames:
    {
        oper: 'action', 
        addoper: 'insert', 
        editoper: 'update', 
        deloper: 'delete'
    },
});
```

I don't see that any of my code is affecting the data sent in POST.  I don't have any JavaScript other than a couple items such as a select menu to control `groupingView` and to display the form edit dialog when a row is double-clicked.

=== EDIT 2 ===
PHP: `return print_r($_POST);`

...

```
Array
(
    [_search] => false
    [nd] => 1402930981946
    [rows] => 30
    [page] => 1
    [sidx] => metaownerid asc, 
    [sord] => asc
)
```

Comment: You should include **JavaScript** code of jqGrid which you use. `sidx` don't contains typically no `asc` suffix.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for the response.  I haven't knowingly changed what `sidx` contains.  How can `sidx` be changed?  The grid and pager are really pretty basic.  The code I added into to my question is most all of it.

Comment: You are welcome! One can see that `sidx` will be sent with `metaownerid asc` value which is not in the code which you posted. I suppose that you included not full code here. Do you specified `sortname` option additionally or you used `groupingView`? You should include the code too. Do you implemented **server side** paging and sorting? If you have no so much rows (less then 10000) then you should consider to use `loadonce: true` option and to return *all* rows at once from the server.

Comment: Correct, this is obviously not the entire code - things I did no paste, for example, are `caption`, `height`, etc.  I don't have `sortname` specified though I had `groupingView` (commenting out had no impact).  The server-side paging is what I was starting to implement when I found this odd behavior.  Currently I have 135k rows and the total is expected to grow into single-digit millions, maybe double-digit.  How can I change `sidx`?

Comment: Ohhh, I as indicated in my previous comment I commented out `groupingView` which had no impact.  What I failed to comment was `grouping` which has now been handled.  This affected POST in that `sidx` now no longer contains a value.  I am going to play around with this some more to see how I can put together my desired paging and sorting.  Will add additional comments and add to the original question later.  Thanks again @Oleg!

Comment: I could explain the described effect only if you used grouping. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:grouping). In any way you should post the code which you use. It's really difficult to guess about the reason.

Comment: So I now have control of server-side paging and server-side searching.  Winning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `grouping` and `groupView` was the culprit causing the `POST` variables.  Once I explored those jqGrid options with various testing I arrived at:

```
grouping: true, 
groupingView: 
{
//  groupField: '', 
    groupColumnShow: [true], 
    groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'], 
    groupCollapse: false, 
//  groupOrder: '', 
    groupSummary: [true], 
    groupDataSorted: true
}
```

These settings resulted in more desirable POST variables and once I had a grip on what was being submitted and under what circumstances I was able to handle the remaining manipulation in PHP.  I now have basic server-side paging.

It may be of note that I intentionally left `groupField` and `groupOrder` commented out in my code.

Thanks for your assistance, @Oleg.